# Can't use jestjs in Windows 7 64 bits

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to use jest to unit test a react application.
I followed this guide, [Test React Components Using Jest (on Windows)](http://ryanlanciaux.github.io/blog/2014/08/02/using-jest-for-testing-react-components-on-windows/), but I'm encountering the following issues:

[image: Error screenshot]

I'm running Python 2.7.10, using Visual Studio 2013, on Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Jest currently only supports Node version 0.10.x

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/243

Try using nvm to switch to a compatible version of Node.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm

I had the exact same issue about a week ago, switching to 0.10.33 resolved it.